# .htaccess applied to 1 file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment i've got a `.htaccess` file applied to `news.php` in the `news` subdirectory. Is there  anyway to get rid of the sub directory, move news.php to the main directory and apply this htaccess rule so anyone who accesses the file gets their URL appended?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news.php?post_id=$1&post_name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Whenever I put news.php into my main directory, then add the above code to that .htaccess, everything gets directed to it, not just calls to the specific file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to check if the url starts with news:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/
```

You can add a `?` in the end if you want the trailing slash optional.